How to speed up a dask delayed compute of a large dictionary?
I need to run a random forest classifier that I've put into a function ~ 10,000 times - because I sample randomly each time. I am trying to use dask delayed on a slurm-scheduled HPC cluster. My script works but I would like to know if there's some improvements I can make to make it faster
This is the basic outline of the script I'm running and it works fine but it is quite slow. The total time for 500x is 22 minutes... so 10000x times will take me 7h...
My python script using dask.delayed
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from Bio import SeqIO
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_mpi import initialize
import gc

import time

start = time.time()
print(start)

# CONNECT TO DISTRIBUTED CLUSTER
initialize()
client = Client()

# THIS FUNCTION IS PARALLELIZED ACROSS MULTIPLE WORKERS
@dask.delayed(nout=2)
def run_the_classifier(data_df_merged_balanced):
    data_df_merged_balanced = data_df_merged_balanced.groupby('Ecosystem_Type').sample(n=127)
    # Import train_test_split function
    
    X=data_df_merged_balanced.iloc[:,0:5787] # Features
    y=data_df_merged_balanced['Ecosystem_Type']  # Labels
    y = pd.get_dummies(y, dtype=int)
    # Split dataset into training set and test set
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y) # 80% training and 20% test

    # Create a Gaussian Classifier
    clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10000,max_depth=5, class_weight='balanced_subsample')

    #Train the model using the training sets y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

    # test the model using the 30% test dataset
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

    # get accuracy
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    feature_imp = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_,index=data_df_numerical.columns).sort_values(ascending=False)

    return accuracy, feature_imp

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# A bunch of dataframe operations are here that produce data_df_merged_balanced - that is passed to the function
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

accuracy_dict = {}
importance_dict = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, 500):
        accuracy, feature_imp = run_the_classifier(data_df_merged_balanced)
        accuracy_dict[i] = accuracy
        importance_dict[i] = feature_imp
        # client.run(gc.collect)
        print(i)
    time_sent = time.time()
    # print(time_sent)
    result_accuracy_dict = dask.compute(accuracy_dict)[0]
    result_imp_dict = dask.compute(importance_dict)[0]
    time_after_computing = time.time()

print(f"elapsed time to compute {i+1}: {time_after_computing - time_sent}")
df_importances = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_imp_dict)
df_importances_mean = df_importances.mean(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False)
df_importances_mean.to_csv('averaged_feature_importances_500.csv')
print(df_importances_mean.head(n=20))
mean_accuracy = np.array(list(result_accuracy_dict.values())).mean()
mean_accuracy_ser = pd.Series(result_accuracy_dict)
mean_accuracy_ser.to_csv('accuracy_scores_500.csv')
end = time.time()
print(f"total elapsed time: {end - start}")   
print(mean_accuracy)


client.close()

Most of the time taken is at the dask.compute step - not sure how to speed this up??
Slurm script used to submit the python script
This is my slurm script that I use to submit my python script. I am using 15 workers and 200G - if I increase the number of workers, I get many "unmanaged or memory leak" warnings or garbage collect warnings. I also get these garbage collection warnings when I run more than 1000 sequences.
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=dask-py           # Job name
#SBATCH --nodes=1                    # Run all processes on a 10 node
#SBATCH --ntasks=15                  # Number of tasks (MPI workers)
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1            # Number of CPU cores per task
#SBATCH --mem=200G                   # Job memory request
#SBATCH --partition=standard,short,long,fat
#SBATCH --output=dask-py%j.log       # Standard output and error log
#SBATCH --error=dask-py%j.err       # Standard output and error log


echo "Running Dask-MPI"

module load mpi/openmpi/4.1.1

source conda.sh

conda activate working-env  # Activate conda environment 

mpirun --oversubscribe -np 15 python3 RF_model_biome_predict_loop.py


'''
# mpirun -np argument needs 2 more workers than what you want for your script
# np rank 0 is for the scheduler
# np rank 1 is for python client process (distribution)
# remaining are workers for your script
'''

Warnings Examples
2024-10-21 17:16:21,239 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged
 memory: 10.06 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 12.50 GiB

or
2024-10-22 12:59:46,569 - distributed.utils_perf - INFO - full garbage collection released 441.47 MiB from 44 reference cycles (threshold: 9.54 MiB)

Any improvements on my workflow or script will be super helpful! I am new to dask and parallelization of code

Hi! How much time takes one execution of the training without Dask, did you compare it to the time you get when launching in parallel?  How big is data_df_merged_balanced, you should probably scatter it ahead of time. Could you do the grouping before using it in the Delayed call?
